# How do I convert this JPQL to CriteriaBuilder on H2?

Tags: java, spring-data, spring-data-jpa, h2, criteria-api

I'm trying to convert this query

```
@Query( "select l from Log l order by l.created desc, l.entry asc " )
Page<Log> findAllCustomJpql( Pageable pageable );
```

which generates this sql

```
Hibernate: select count(log0_.id) as col_0_0_ from log log0_
Hibernate: select log0_.id as id1_0_, log0_.created as created2_0_, log0_.entry as entry3_0_ from log log0_ order by log0_.created desc, log0_.entry asc limit ?
```

to a criteria builder query, using specifications

```
@RequestMapping( method = RequestMethod.GET, path = "spec")
Page<Log> getLogsBySpecification( final Pageable pageable ) {
    return repository.findAll( ( root, query, cb ) -> {
        query.orderBy(
                cb.desc( root.get( "created" ) ),
                cb.asc( root.get( "entry" ) )
        );
        return null;
    }, pageable);
}
```

which is doing the following

```
2015-10-17 19:33:40.720  WARN 10498 --- [nio-8080-exec-6] o.h.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper   : SQL Error: 90016, SQLState: 90016
2015-10-17 19:33:40.721 ERROR 10498 --- [nio-8080-exec-6] 
o.h.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper   : Column "LOG0_.ENTRY" must be in the GROUP BY list; SQL statement:
select count(log0_.id) as col_0_0_ from log log0_ order by log0_.created desc, log0_.entry asc [90016-188]
2015-10-17 19:33:40.750 ERROR 10498 --- [nio-8080-exec-6] o.a.c.c.C.[.[.[/].[dispatcherServlet]    : Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaSystemException: could not extract ResultSet; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.GenericJDBCException: could not extract ResultSet] with root cause
org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLException: Column "LOG0_.ENTRY" must be in the GROUP BY list; SQL statement:
select count(log0_.id) as col_0_0_ from log log0_ order by log0_.created desc, log0_.entry asc [90016-188]
```

I personally think the sql is valid, if ill advised, but doesn't seem to be valid for h2. How can I correct my criteria in order to generate the results I want?

Answer (score 0):

This is really not the same query but I do believe it comes to the same effect.

```
@RequestMapping( method = RequestMethod.GET, path = "spec" )
Page<Log> getLogsBySpecification( final Pageable pageable ) {
    return repository.findAll( ( root, query, cb ) -> {
        query.orderBy(
                cb.desc( root.get( "created" ) ),
                cb.asc( root.get( "entry" ) )
        );

        query.groupBy( root.get( "id" ) );
        return null;
    }, pageable );
}
```

I am kind of wondering if the fact that the specification continues to apply the order by is a bug... ultimately this seems related to [this bug](https://jira.spring.io/browse/DATAJPA-723)